# $2x^2-16x+28$ into standard form

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

I think I'm just doing something stupid here, because I know it's not hard.

Here's what I did:
$$y-28+{\_\_\_}=2x^2-16+{\_\_\_}$$
$$y-28+{\_\_\_}=2(x^2-8+{\_\_\_})$$
$$y-28+16= 2(x^2-8+16)$$
$$y-12=2(x-4)^2$$
$$y=2(x-4)^2+12$$

But then it ends up with different vertex than the original quadratic. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In the third line, you added 16 to the left side, and 32 to the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$y=2(x-4)^2 - 4 \equiv 2x^2 - 16x + 28$$

Your mistake was in the third line, were you added $16$ to the LHS and $32$ to the RHS. $2 \cdot 16 \neq 16$.

Comment: Okay, I forgot that part. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad you found the mistake. :-)